# Any way to auto execute a file in windows

Tags: exploit

MS-Word gives the functionality of **OLE** In which we embed any link in document and on any event it would go to that link and download the file.
The file is stored in the TEMP directory of the WORD. 
How can a hacker executes that file say from the OLE it downloads an **.exe** but there need to have something that can execute.
Is there any way an attacker could run this file on my system ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a very large security hole, so no, generally speaking, there isn't any way to do that. There have been security bugs in the past that permitted things like this in specific scenarios (such as downloading a file that executes when viewed in Windows Explorer), but they were patched. There are ways to do this if you have arbitrary control over where the file downloads to (in fact, that's relatively easy; just drop it in the user's "Startup" folder in their Start Menu or modify some shortcut that the user runs regularly), or can otherwise make certain changes to the file system, but just dropping a file in a temp directory won't do it.

There are ways for an Office document to ask the user for permission to do unsafe things, and those unsafe things can include running programs. However, these requests will cause somewhat-scary-looking warning dialogs that users much approve the risk of before the attacker's code will run.

Also, there's usually no need to drop a file on the user's system, if you have some way to execute an arbitrary program. Run the program over the network or (if you can use command-line parameters) just have CMD or Powershell execute a script that you stuffed into the command line.